# Angular, wait for two directives to be loaded and initiate another external library

Tags: angularjs

The draw2d library, when initialized, it traverses the dom and does it's magic.

The trick is to initiate it, after everything is loaded.

It will control a menu and a canvas, which are both angular js directives with some extra classes needed for the draw2d library to work.

```
angular.module('test').directive('load-menu', function () {
console.log('i am the menu for the draw2d library');
});

angular.module('test').directive('the-canvas', function () {
console.log('i am the canvas for the draw2d library');
});
```

Now, is there a way for me to know, from inside the controller, which holds the two directive, when they are loaded and instantiate the draw2d library?

```
angular.module('test').controller('areTheDirectivesLoaded', function() {
   // are the directives loaded?
   // instantiate my library!
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe such things are lazy loaded, but you could do a crazy hack using rootScope:

```
angular.module('test').directive('load-menu', function ($rootScope) {
    console.log('i am the menu for the draw2d library');
    // assuming this directive loads the menu
    $rootScope.menuDirectiveLoaded = true;
});

angular.module('test').directive('the-canvas', function ($rootScope) {
    console.log('i am the canvas for the draw2d library');
    // assuming this directive loads the canvas
    $rootScope.canvasDirectiveLoaded = true;
});

angular.module('test').controller('areTheDirectivesLoaded', function($rootScope) {

   // create two watchers for your directive values and if both become true, instantiate the library
   var keepGoing = true;
   $rootScope.$watch('canvasDirectiveLoaded', function(newVal, oldVal){
       if(newVal === true && $rootScope.menuDirectiveLoaded === true && keepGoing){
           ; // instantiate library
           keepGoing = false; // so as not to instantiate twice
       }
   });

   $rootScope.$watch('menuDirectiveLoaded', function(newVal, oldVal){
       if(newVal === true && $rootScope.canvasDirectiveLoaded === true && keepGoing){
           ; // instantiate library
           keepGoing = false; // so as not to instantiate twice
       }
   });



});
```